# javascript ES6 class/method scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scopes

I can't figure out how to correct the context of my methods.

I have this class:

```
export default class Handler {

    constructor() {
        // init
    }

    handleMessage(channel, user, message) {
        this.handleDefault(channel, user, message);
    }

    handleDefault(chanenl, user, message) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

it is called by this method and class

```
export default class Bot {

    constructor() {
        this.irc     = irc // has an event emitter irc.event
        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.readIRC();
    }

    readIRC() {
        this.irc.event.on('message', this.handler.handleMessage);
    }
}
```

The problem is in the first class inside handleMessage is this not the class anymore but the eventEmitter so I can't call my handleDefault method.

How do I work with contexts corretly in ES6 ?

Comment: You seem to be asking about the **`this` context**, not the *scope*.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to bind `handleMessage` to `this.handler`, either with

- `Function.prototype.bind`

  ```
  this.irc.event.on('message', this.handler.handleMessage.bind(this.handler));
  ```
- or with an Arrow function,

  ```
  this.irc.event.on('message', () => this.handler.handleMessage());
  ```

In both these cases, when the `handleMessage` function is invoked on `message` event, the `this` within `handleMessage` will refer the `this.handle` object.

---

If you like to pass arguments to the event handler, you can define the arrow function like this

```
this.irc.event.on('message', (err, msg) => this.handler.handleMessage(err, msg));
```

Comment: If I use an Arrow function how do I pass arguments correctly.

Comment: @danielps1: The same way you do it in `handleMessage` itself: define the parameters and pass them along. Or use rest parameter and spread argument.

Comment: oh yeah. I actually had it correct just had a stupid typo. thank you!

Comment: @danielps1 Exactly like Felix explained. I just included a simple example. PTAL.